# Function that finds length of a number is returning an invalid output when number contains all 9s as digits

Tags: c, cs50

I have a function that returns the length of a number by dividing it by `10` until it is less than `1` and greater than `0`.

**Ex.**

`12345 => 5`

`83 => 2`

The issue is that `999999999999999`s length should be `15` but my function returns `16`. The function works fine for everything else...

**Ex.**

`123456789123456 => 15`

**C code**

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int find_num_len(float num);
int counter = 0;

int main(void) {

    long long int cc_num;

    do {
        cc_num = get_long_long("Number:");
    }

    while( cc_num < 0);
    find_num_len(cc_num);
}


int find_num_len(float num) {
    if (num > 0 && num < 1) {
      printf("%i\n", counter);
      return counter;
    }

    counter ++;

    find_num_len(num/10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your issue is a matter of finite precision. When you divide a number so close to a power of 10 by 10 repeatedly, you're going to get a result extremely close to a whole number (15.99999...)- so close that the computer can't differentiate between it being slightly less than X or X itself. In this case, it gets rounded up to 16.

Comment: Step 1: `float num` --> `long long num`

Comment: Try printing `num`. Clearly there is something wrong with using `float`!

Comment: @MateenUlhaq , I already tried that. I get **Segmentation fault**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're converting `long long int` to `float` unnecessarily. The mantissa of IEEE-754 32-bit `float` is 24 bits. And `2^24 = 16777216`, which is the maximum possible number that can be represented with guaranteed precision.

This is one way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_num_len(long long int num) {
    return num >= 10 ? 1 + find_num_len(num / 10) : 1;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", find_num_len(999999999999999));
    return 0;
}
```

Or if you want to avoid the recursion:

```
int find_num_len(long long int num) {
    int count = 1;

    while (num >= 10) {
        num = num / 10;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: How does the first one not go on forever? Because whatever number divided by 10 is always going to be greater than 0. Just curious.

Comment: `39 / 10 = 3`. Integer division rounds towards `0`.

Comment: Using `do {
        num = num / 10;
        count++;
    } while (num > 0);` would allow `find_num_len(0)` to properly return 1.

Comment: @chux Why should `find_num_len(0) == 1` be the canonical definition? For binary "strings", `32 - clz(0) == 0`. I could change it so that the behavior is equivalent to `string(num).length()`, as you expect, but that makes the recursion require a separate helper function.

Comment: `find_num_len(0) == 1` is a more intuitive answer as most times zero is written as "0", one digit and not "", zero digits.  IMO, that matches OP goal of "finds length of a number".  IAC, as OP is only "when number contains all 9s as digits", code is free to return 0, 1 or anything on `find_num_len(0)`.  Your call.  Recursion is handled with `int find_num_len(unsigned long long int num) {
    return num >= 10 ? 1 + find_num_len(num / 10) : 1;
}`, extra helper function not needed.

Comment: @chux I suppose most people would use this as a replacement for `string(num).length()`, so I'll change it.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a rounding error. The first integer that can’t be represented accurately by float is 2^24, approx 16 million which is way smaller than 15 9’s in a row.

Try using double which can go as high as 2^54; (from memory, best to check the ieee 754 spec to verify) which can represent Ints as high as ~1e16.

Or - compute the log10 of the number, add one, then truncate.

Len = floor (log10(number) + 1)

Comment: Using FP math to  for an integer problem runs a risk: `log10(number)`  may return a result of `x.9999....` when `x+1` is expected leading to an incorrect answer for OP.  Also troubles with `number == 0` or `number < 0`.  Of course these later inputs are not all 9s.

Comment: 2^24 is exactly represented in IEEE 754 basic 32-bit binary arithmetic. 2^24+1 is not. For 64-bit, 2^53+1 is the first integer that is not represented.

Comment: thanks for the catch - I pecked my answer into my iPhone in a bit of a hurry, and it's been a while since I've looked at float format.